# JPA mapping unidirectional @ManyToMany with struts2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, struts2, hibernate-mapping

Hy guys,

I have a problem with the `@OneToMany` unidirectional association.
Basically in my model I have two entities: `Player` and `Role`. I map this relationship with a `@ManyToMany` cause: One player can have more Role and a Role can be associated with multiple Players.

**Player.java**

```
@Entity
public class Player implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Role> roles;
    ...
}
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String roleName;
    ...
}
```

I print my player list with struts2 like this:

```
<table>
...
   <s:iterator value="players" status="player">
     <tr>
     <td><s:property value="name"/></td>
     <td><s:property value="price"/></td>
     <td>
         <s:iterator value="roles" status="role">
             <s:property value="roleName"/>
         </s:itetator>
     </td>
  </s:iterator>
...
</table>
```

And I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: no session or session was closed.
```

Why I'm getting this error? It is wrong the JPA mapping? 
I tried to remove (just for a check) the role inner iterator and I can see the players table well, but obviously without roles that I need.

**NOTE:** I tried to debug the application and when I was in the action, I got the `List<Player>`, I expanded one Player and I saw the `List<Roles>` with a `Persistent Bag` variable, I tried to maximized again but I was unable to get the `roleName` variable.

Can someone help me to figure out the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loading one-to-many associations is a waste of time, if you need to create a list of roles for particular player just call a query by passing a player id.

Comment: Actually no for just one player, but for a player's list.

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: Something like this:  `select p from Player p join p.roles r where p.id = :id`?

Comment: Yes, something like this but different owner. Note proper naming makes your code more readable, e.g. *ball* is a singular, but *balls* are plural.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access hibernate result which is lazy initialized after closing your hibernate session. That's why you are getting this error. Change initialization type to eager by fetchType.

Comment: Sorry @Kanagaraj M, I forgot to write it, I already try to do like this with the annotation `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, but it is the same.

Comment: Then print your values with session itself. If mapping is wrong you will get mapping exception only not this.

Comment: Sorry could you be a little bit more precise please?

Comment: Try to print all values with in hibernate session itself.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if the EAGER solution does not work, I think your only option is to keep the transaction open while you fetch all the data. So basically:

1. open transaction.

2.- Query the database.

3.- fetch all data and move it to another data structure (some DTO) that will containt only the data that you want. This will go to the roles as well.

4.- close transaction.

5.- generate response using the DTO structure

Comment: And how can I open and close transaction if I'm using JTA and CMT? With this approach the demarcation transaction is managed by the container.

Comment: @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public XXX methodA() {}

I use this notation to demarc the transactions in a method. After the method is finished, the transaction is closed